# Changing the Lyx UI

Tags: lyx

Is any way to change the look of the Lyx workspace to something more appealing?

I know it's not WYSIWYG, I'm just wondering if the look of the typing window can be changed to something resembling Word or a page view sort of look.

The far left aligned massive vertical space thing isn't so aesthetically appealing or welcoming for sitting down to work for 8 hours at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this off topic exactly??  The faq says "Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc."  Is that not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lyx is a free software, so you can *easely* change what you want in the UI and then recompile the software for you.

If you want that someone do this change for you, you have 2 solutions:

- either pay a developer to do this job
- or try to convince the Lyx community that your workspace will be better than the existing one by filling a bug report [here](http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome)

Comment: Got it.  Have people in the community made any alternative UIs they've created available?  I searched but didn't find any...

Comment: @DirkCalloway I'm not using Lyx, but I've just checked a bit the git repository and I think that the UI seems to be hard-coded. So changing the UI means forking the project... and I've never heard about a fork of Lyx.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it probably wasn't easy to do, but figured it'd be worth checking.

Comment: I've not heard of alternate UIs. You can change the buttons easily.

Comment: A partial solution is implemented already - in the settings, you can find a "limit text width" option for full screen mode. Det appropriately, you will get margins on both sides.